# Grouping data without calling aggregation function in pyspark

Tags: group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my data.

```
CouponNbr,ItemNbr,TypeCode,DeptNbr,MPQ  
10,2,1,10,1    
10,3,4,50,2    
11,2,1,10,1    
11,3,4,50,2
```

I want to group it in spark in such a way such that it looks like this:

```
CouponNbr,ItemsInfo    
10,[[2,1,10,1],[3,4,50,2]]    
11,[[2,1,10,1],[3,4,50,2]]
```

I try to group it by and convert it to dictionary with the following code,

```
df.groupby("CouponNbr").apply(lambda x:x[["ItemNbr","TypeCode","DeptNbr","MPQ"]].to_dict("r"))
```

But this is in pandas and it returns the following

```
CouponNbr,ItemsInfo    
10,[{[ItemNbr:2,TypeCode:1,DeptNbr:10,MPQ:1],[ItemNbr:3,TypeCode:4,DeptNbr:50,MPQ:2]}]    
11,[{[ItemNbr:2,TypeCode:1,DeptNbr:10,MPQ:1],[ItemNbr:3,TypeCode:4,DeptNbr:50,MPQ:2]}]
```

Is there a way I could achieve the format I need in pyspark? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can firstly collect columns into a single array column using the `array` function and then do `groupby.agg` using `collect_list`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupBy('CouponNbr').agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.array('ItemNbr', 'TypeCode', 'DeptNbr', 'MPQ')
    ).alias('ItemsInfo')
).show(2, False)

+---------+------------------------------+
|CouponNbr|ItemsInfo                     |
+---------+------------------------------+
|10       |[[2, 1, 10, 1], [3, 4, 50, 2]]|
|11       |[[2, 1, 10, 1], [3, 4, 50, 2]]|
+---------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I even tried this:    def jsonToDataFrame(json, schema=None):
  # SparkSessions are available with Spark 2.0+
  reader = spark.read
  if schema:
    reader.schema(schema)
  return reader.json(sc.parallelize([json])), and converted the dataframe to json before passing it as a parameter to this function. That worked as well. Thanks :)